# Conformally flat manifold with zero scalar

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I would like to ask the following : Is there any example of a compact conformally flat Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ with $n\geq 4$ which is not flat and has zero scalar curvature?

Comment: Do you want an *explicit* example or a proof that one exists? I think it is likely that there are such $(M^4,g)$, but I don't know how to make an explicit example. The idea for existence is to make a family of compact conformally flat $4$-manifolds by taking conformally flat connected sums of compact space forms, some with Yamabe energy $>0$ and some with Yamabe energy $<0$.  Varying the parameters in the connected sum should make the Yamabe energy vary, so it should be possible to make one with zero Yamabe energy. Then, by Schoen, it will have a conformal metric with zero scalar curvature.

Answer (score 8):

Take a unit sphere $S^2$ and a hyperbolic surface $X$. Then the product $S^ 2 \times X$ is not flat and has zero scalar curvature. Also it is conformally flat by a paper

Simon Salamon (2009) Complex structures and conformal geometry. In: BOLLETTINO DELLA UNIONE MATEMATICA ITALIANA, vol. 9, pp. 199-224

as per editor Holonomia.

Comment: @ katz: Just a doubt: your product $S^2 \times X$ is conformally flat as the OP asked ? it is well-known  that $S^2 \times H^2$ is conformally flat where $H^2$ unit disk with the hyperbolic metric i.e. the universal covering of X.  So $S^2 \times X$ is locally conformally flat. It is obvious that a multiple of the product metric is flat?.

Comment: @katz:  Indeed, your local argument cannot be correct.  In dimensions $n>2$, there are many conformally flat metrics with vanishing scalar curvature that are not flat.  Essentially, they depend on $2$ arbitrary functions of $n{-}1$ variables, and the generic one does *not* have constant sectional curvature.

Comment: In dimensions 4 or higher, conformally flat means the Weyl tensor vanishes. If the scalar curvature also vanishes, there is still the possibility that the trace-free part of the Ricci curvature is non-vanishing. As Robert points out, there are indeed local metrics satisfying this.

Comment: For sure, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Responding to the OP's comments on the [duplicate question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228331/conformally-flat-with-zero-scalar-curvature-2), the example that was given in dimension $4$ can be easily generalized to **higher dimensions**:

> If $(M,g_M)$ has constant sectional curvature $+1$ and $(N,g_N)$ has constant sectional curvature $-1$, then the product manifold $(M\times N,g_M\oplus g_N)$ is conformally flat. This is proved, e.g., in [Besse's book "Einstein manifolds"](https://books.google.com/books?id=6I_XgRJaBL0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see Example 1.167, p. 61).
>   Furthermore, this product manifold has vanishing scalar curvature if and only if $\dim M=\dim N$.

Comment: Did you see the Salamon text?

Comment: @katz: No, I actually could not find a copy online... Can you share one?

Comment: Renatto, I didn't read the paper but Bryant seems to think the result is there. What I was wondering about is the much earlier date of Besse.

Comment: @RenatoG.Bettiol thanks! I couldnt comment since i was new and i had no reputaion..

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer is NO. Namely, if $(M,g)$ is compact, conformally flat and has zero scalar curvature then $g$ is a flat metric. Indeed, by the hypothesis there is a smooth function $f:M \to \mathbb R$ such that $e^f g$ is a flat metric on $M$. Then a finite covering of $M$ is a torus. The metric $g$ then lift to such a torus and by the Gromov-Lawson theorem (see Corollary A in http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/8%5B26%5D.pdf) the lifted metric is flat hence the original $g$ is flat. QED

As Robert Bryant observed I made a mistake assuming that $e^f g$ is a flat metric on $M$. Indeed, conformally flat means that $e^f g$ has constant sectional curvatures so the sectional curvature can be also 1 or -1. Watching the formula for the scalar curvature of a conformal change

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry

it seems that the problem reduce to the question if the number $(n-2)/4(n-1)$ is an eigenvalue of the Laplacian of a compact hyperbolic manifold of dimension $n$.

The same formula allows to rule out the flat case without using Gromov-Lawson theorem. Indeed, if $e^f g$ is flat and $g$ has zero scalar curvature then $e^{n-2}f$ is harmonic hence constant since $M$ is compact. So $g$ is flat.

Comment: @ katz I agree that this is too complicated. But your proof does not seems to use the compactness of the manifold,isn'it?

Comment: @Holonomia:  Your argument is not right either, for, along the way, you argue that a compact conformally flat manifold carries a flat metric (i.e., you do not use the hypothesis that the scalar curvature is zero when you derive this). However, this statement is false for dimensions bigger than $2$:  $S^1\times S^{n-1}$ has a conformally flat metric but has no flat metric when $n>2$.

Comment: @ Robert Bryant: You are right I forgot that the conformal metric can also have constant but non zero sectional curvature. For example, the sphere $S^2$ is conformally flat but has no flat metric...

Comment: @Holonomia:  I'm afraid that you are still making a mistake.  Having $g$ be conformally flat does *not* imply that there is an $f$ such that $e^fg$ has constant sectional curvature.  Again the natural metric $g$ on $M = S^1\times S^{n-1}$ is conformally flat, but, when $n>2$, there is no function $f$ on $M$ such that $e^f g$ has constant sectional curvature.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: just to avoid further mistakes:  What is the definition of conformally flat ?

Comment: "Conformally flat" = "locally conformally flat".

Comment: @Holonomia:  A metric $g$ on $M$ is *conformally flat* if each point $p\in M$ has an open neighborhood $U$ on which there exists a function $f$ such that $e^f g$ is flat *on $U$*.  This condition really should be called 'locally conformally flat', but the common usage is to simply say 'conformally flat', because, in that way, conformally flat becomes something that one can test locally.  Another criterion that is used when $n>3$ is to say that a metric $g$ is conformally flat if its Weyl tensor vanishes. (In dimension $3$, the condition is that its Cotton tensor vanishes.)

Comment: Locally one can always write down $e^{x^2+y^2-z^2-w^2}$ and it will be conformally flat but not flat.  Certainly globally one needs to use compactness as pointed out by @Holonomia.

Comment: @katz But now, with this local definition of conformally flat, what is wrong with your initial answer $S^2  \times X$ where $X$ is a hyperbolic compact surface?

Comment: The metric on $S^2\times X$ is a direct sum of the metrics on the factors. The above metric is a *product* in a certain sense. Did I get it wrong again?  I am having trouble waking up...

Comment: @katz I am sure that, with the standard definition (I assume it is the one given by Robert Bryant), your initial answer solves the OP question. Namely, a product $S^2 \times X$ where $S^2$ is endowed with its canonical metric of constant curvature 1 and $X$ is a compact quotient of the unit disk endowed with its canonical metric of constant curvature -1 i.e. a compact hyperbolic surface.

Comment: @Holonomia, that metric is indeed of zero scalar curvature, but it is not conformally flat.  Do you have reason to think it is?

Comment: You wrote above that "it is well-known that $S^ 2 \times H ^2$ is conformally flat where $H ^2 $ is the unit disk with the hyperbolic metric" but I don't think this is correct.  Each factor is obviously conformally flat but the product is not.

Comment: In general a product of l.c.f manifolds is not l.c.f. But if I recall correctly there is a small miracle that happens when you take the product of the sphere and the hyperbolic space (with curvature +1 and -1, and this works only with these values). I'll try to post the computation later if anybody is interested. Anyway, if I correctly understand the question, this give that $\mathbb{S}^n\times \mathbb{H}^n$ answers the question in even dimensions.

Comment: @ThomasRichard:  Indeed, you are correct.  The product of the unit $2$-sphere (with $K\equiv1$) with the hyperbolic metric (with $K\equiv-1$) on any compact Riemann surface of genus $g\ge2$ gives a conformally flat metric with zero scalar curvature that is not flat.  I forgot about that example when I was proposing a general method to construct families.

Comment: So the original Katz answer was correct.

Comment: @katz: I learn that $S^2 \times H^2$ is conformally flat time ago in the nice paper by Simon Salamon: Complex structures and conformal geometry. In: BOLLETTINO DELLA UNIONE MATEMATICA ITALIANA, vol. 9, pp. 199-224.  The issue is related to the twistor of $S^4$ and there are there is also a nice picture.